# What is the meaning of hash symbol followed by number after IP address when I use nslookup?

Tags: hash, ip, nslookup

When I type command:

$ nslookup [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

The results are:

Server:         XXX.XXX.XX.X

Address:        XXX.XXX.XX.X#NN

Non-authoritative answer:

....

What I want to ask is what is the meaning of the number after the hash symbol and the ip address before it.

Answer (score 1):

The hash and number refer to the network port used by [DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd197515(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)